# Duplicate record add a number if exists

Tags: php

I need to duplicate a record on database, and if this exists add a number next to name, for example:

MyRecord

MyRecord Duplicate 1

If i duplicate again

My Record Duplicate 2 and so on...

I have tried

```
 foreach($records as $record) {
                $nombre = $record->name;
                $newName= $record->name." - DUPLICATED 1";
                //If exists
                if ($nombre = $newName) {
                    $valor = substr($nombre, -1); //Get last value of string, it will be the number, its always at the end.
                    $num = $valor;
                    $int = (int)$num;
                    $float = (float)$num;
                    $float++;
                    $newName= $record->name." - DUPLICATED ".$float;

                    //Second try
                    if ($nombre = $newName) {

                         $valor = substr($nombre, -1); 
                         $num = $valor;
                         $int = (int)$num;
                         $float = (float)$num;
                         $float++;

                        $today = Carbon::now();              
                        DB::table('table')->insert( ...
```

The problem is when the foreach comes again it trieds to insert the value a make a duplicate on name so i have now

Name Duplicate 1

Name Duplicate 2

Name Duplicate 2 -> instead of 3

Comment: `if ($nombre = $newName)` I do believe that you're assigning here, rather than comparing `if ($nombre == $newName)`

Comment: the problem is, it doesnt seems to find the lastest record with same name...i think that the issue, so if there is a same name just do float++ and it will have a new name...thats my logic...maybe im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it in this way

```
do {
                //do while name exists
                $clone++;
                $newName = $record->name." - CLONED - ".$clone;
                $nameExists= DB::table('record')
                                    ->where('name', '=', $newName)
                                    ->first();

             } while ($nameExists);
```